# Rescaled certain columns to specific mean and standard deviation in R

Tags: r, dplyr, psych

Given a dataframe as follows, how can I rescale `v5` so that the `mean` is `100` and the `standard deviation` is `15`?

```
head(df, n=5)
```

Out:

```
v1  v2    v3   v4   v5 
65  1   121.12  4   27
98  1   89.36   4   25
85  1   115.44  4   27
83  1   99.45   3   25
115 1   92.75   4   27
98  0   107.90  1   18
```

I have tried with `psych` package but final `df` is not correct for last column:

```
library(psych)
library(tidyverse)
v5.rescaled <- df %>% rescale(df$v5, mean = 100, sd = 15)
df$v5.rescaled
```

Out:

```
t.t.scale.x.....sd...mean.
121.11985               
89.35994                
115.43986               
99.44991                
92.74993
```

But `head(df, n=5)` is not correct for rescaled `v5`:

```
    v1  v2     v3   v4  v5        v5.rescaled
1   65  1   121.12  4   27  <data.frame [5 × 1]>
2   98  1   89.36   4   25  <data.frame [5 × 1]>
3   85  1   115.44  4   27  <data.frame [5 × 1]>
4   83  1   99.45   3   25  <data.frame [5 × 1]>
5   115 1   92.75   4   27  <data.frame [5 × 1]>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Please try to post a valid reprex next time.  This will save others the trouble of having to manually reproduce your input data.  Also, it is not immediately clear how your first code chunk referring to a df with columns `v1` - `v5` relates to the subsequent code chunk referring to `df$mother.iq`.
2. The help file for `psych::rescale()` specifically states that the input, `x`, should be *a matrix or data frame*. I suspect this is why the output you get is not what you were expecting.
3. While you can use `psych::rescale()`, a better alternative that offers more flexibility  may be to forego the additional dependency on the `{psych}` package altogether and, instead, simply manually rescale the columns as required.  The two approaches are illustrated in the reprex below:

```r
# load libraries
library(tidyverse)

# define data as per OP
df <- data.frame(
          v1 = c(65L, 98L, 85L, 83L, 115L, 98L),
          v2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L),
          v3 = c(121.12, 89.36, 115.44, 99.45, 92.75, 107.9),
          v4 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L),
          v5 = c(27L, 25L, 27L, 25L, 27L, 18L)
)

# rescale via psych::rescale using entire data frame
df %>% psych::rescale(mean = 100, sd = 15)
#>          v1        v2        v3        v4        v5
#> 1  77.38682 106.12372 119.90143 108.25723 109.31746
#> 2 106.46091 106.12372  82.24089 108.25723 100.71673
#> 3  95.00748 106.12372 113.16617 108.25723 109.31746
#> 4  93.24541 106.12372  94.20546  95.87139 100.71673
#> 5 121.43847 106.12372  86.26070 108.25723 109.31746
#> 6 106.46091  69.38138 104.22535  71.09970  70.61416

# if you only want to do this for specific columns, do it manually by targeting
# columns using dplyr::mutate_at(), an anonymous function, and scale (from base
# R):
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(v4, v5), function(x) scale(x)*15 + 100)
#>    v1 v2     v3        v4        v5
#> 1  65  1 121.12 108.25723 109.31746
#> 2  98  1  89.36 108.25723 100.71673
#> 3  85  1 115.44 108.25723 109.31746
#> 4  83  1  99.45  95.87139 100.71673
#> 5 115  1  92.75 108.25723 109.31746
#> 6  98  0 107.90  71.09970  70.61416
```

Comment: Sorry for the inconveniance. I modified `mother.iq` to `v5` to make it simpler. For data, I don't know yet how to copy dataframe from `rmarkdown` result to stackoverflow, as in Pandas with `pd.read_clipboard`.

Comment: For reproducible data frames, I generally recommend either using the `dput` function (base R) or one of the functions from the `{datapasta}` package that allow you to paste data frames in R's memory into a script.  More generally, I'd highly recommend the `{reprex}` package.  It has several fantastic functions for creating valid _copy-&-paste_ style reprexes.

Comment: `df %>% mutate_at(vars(v4, v5), function(x) scale(x)*15 + 100)`, does this transform `v4` and `v5` to `mean=100` and `std=15`? Can we apply `rescale` function from `psych` or use `scale` function to do that?

Comment: I believe so (at least, the output for those columns appear to be identical to what is produced by `psych::rescale`).  Mechanically, the `vars()` argument inside `mutate_at` specifies which columns from `df` should be targeted.

Comment: Ok, but I find it didn't change the original `df`, when I print(df), it returns the original one, not the one after `rescaled`, and how can call new column as `v5.rescaled`?

Comment: It wouldn't have changed `df` as no assignment has taken place.  If you wanted to add a rescaled version of `v5` only to `df` (this is not clear from your OP), then the following should work: `df <- df %>% mutate(v5.rescaled = scale(v5)*15 + 100)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210919/discussion-between-hendrikvanb-and-ahbon).